# Spring integration : does SpringApplicationContext call @ServiceActivator in config?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am reading Spring integration source code, and I have some questions understanding the workflow:

Does the @SpringBootApplication class, when calling `application.run()`, will call directly beans annotated using @ServiceActivator ? For example in my config file I have :

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = test)
public MessageHandler myHandler() {
   return new SomeHandler();
}
```

when the `application.run()` is fired, the method `handleRequestMessage()` of `SomeHandler` will be called ? Am I understanding it right ?

Comment: The ServiceActivator links a Handler to the channel. So the message will be called when there is a message in the input channel name "test"

Comment: hi thank you for your explanation, so basically @ServiceActivator does nothing but tells the channel what handler to use when receiving a message into channel "test" right ?

Comment: exactly. Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to understand that there are two parts of this matter:

1. Configuration phase when Spring parses all the annotations to register beans in the `AppplicaitonContext`. This way even that `@ServiceActivator` is consulted and a event-driven endpoint is registered as a bean as well.
2. Runtime part of Spring Integration environment. Here the mentioned endpoint is subscribed to the `inputChannel` and when message is has arrived the `handleRequestMessage()` is triggered from that `SomeHandler`. That's why it is called "service activator".

You probably need to make yourself familiar with EIP first of all: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ to understand what is messaging and why there are endpoints and channels in between. Then you go to Spring Integration docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/index.html and realize for yourself that this framework provides a bunch of out-of-the-box components for this or that EIP which may be registered automaticaly in the application context by just declaring some annotation.